# How to make progam to run by the schedule, if it is closed or not .NET 7.0 MAUI

Tags: c#, .net, maui, .net-7.0

Maybe this type of task is not often used, because no matter how much I search, I can't find anything useful.
However, i need to do something like alarm. Imagine, your phone is turned off or only program is off or program can be turned on, however, by schedule, program will open certain window and start some music. About music its not the deal.
Goal is to make program run by schedule. I know one way by "Foreground Service", by doing timer or "TaskScheduler". But this will be uncomfortable, because of displaying in notifications and spending some process resources.
I will apriciate all kind of help.

I tried do something with xamarin.essentials, but some classes has been removed, like Alarm Notification like that.

Comment: Are you trying to do something like background scheduling? For iOS, iOS has a lot of restrictions on the background, you can check Apple's explanation: [iOS background execution restrictions](https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/685525). For Android, you can try to use Job Scheduler, check the official documentation: [Android Job Scheduler](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/android/platform/android-job-scheduler).

Answer (score 1):

Try using the Timer class and the BackgroundService class.

Example:
In your class you want to run on schedule add those usings:

```
using System;
using System.Threading;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting;
```

Create a method called "ExcecuteAsync". Write your code, which should run on schedule, in this method.
Example:

```
public class ScheduledTask : BackgroundService
{
    protected override async Task ExecuteAsync(CancellationToken stoppingToken)
{
    while (!stoppingToken.IsCancellationRequested)
    {
        // Run your code here

        await Task.Delay(TimeSpan.FromMinutes(30), stoppingToken);
        }
    }
}
```

Here you run the code eveey 30 seconds.

And in the `Program.cs` file add following code to create and run your ScheduledTask:

```
using Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting;

var builder = MauiApp.CreateBuilder();
builder
.UseMauiApp<ScheduledTask>()
.Build()
.Run();
```

Hope this helps. If not, please do not hesitate to reply.

---

Edit:

"Your answer was helpful, but example throws error that "The type 'AlarmNotifier.cs.ScheduledTask' cannot be used as type parameter 'TApp' in the generic type or method 'AppHostBuilderExtensions.UseMauiApp(MauiAppBuilder)'. There is no implicit reference conversion from 'AlarmNotifier.cs.ScheduledTask' to 'Microsoft.Maui.IApplication'." It says that ScheduledTask is not the app, and it's right, but how else you can run this ExecuteAsync method?"

To fix the remaining issue you have to use 'UseMaui' instead of 'UseMauiApp'.

add this to your `program.cs` file:

```
using Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting;

var builder = MauiApp.CreateBuilder();
builder.UseMaui<App>();
var app = builder.Build();

var scheduledTask = new ScheduledTask();
await scheduledTask.StartAsync(CancellationToken.None);

await app.RunAsync();
```

then update your ScheduledTask class. Remove the'BackgroundService', because we don't use 'ExcecuteAsync' anymore. Instead use 'StartAsync'.

Update your Scheduledtask class like this:

```
public class ScheduledTask
{
  private Timer _timer;

  public async Task StartAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
  {
    _timer = new Timer(DoWork, null, TimeSpan.Zero, 
    TimeSpan.FromMinutes(30));

    await Task.CompletedTask;
  }

  private void DoWork(object state)
  {
    // Your code goes here
  }
}
```

hope it works this time.

Comment: Your answer was helpful, but example throws error that "The type 'AlarmNotifier.cs.ScheduledTask' cannot be used as type parameter 'TApp' in the generic type or method 'AppHostBuilderExtensions.UseMauiApp<TApp>(MauiAppBuilder)'. There is no implicit reference conversion from 'AlarmNotifier.cs.ScheduledTask' to 'Microsoft.Maui.IApplication'." It says that ScheduledTask is not the app, and it's right, but how else you can run this ExecuteAsync method?

Comment: I also thought this would help, but didn't fully understand "await app.RunAsync();" does it starts async tasks? However, there are CS1061 'MauiAppBuilder' does not contain a definition for 'UseMaui' and no accessible extension method 'UseMaui' accepting a first argument of type 'MauiAppBuilder' could be found. Ok there we can write UseMauiApp, it does'nt cause other mistakes, but there is CS1929 'MauiApp' does not contain a definition for 'RunAsync' and the best extension method overload 'HostingAbstractionsHostExtensions.RunAsync(IHost, CancellationToken)' requires a receiver of type 'IHost'